# How to access Face3 Vector3 Three.js

Tags: three.js

I am trying to change the face color based on whether any of the vertices in any of the Vector3 inside a Face3 are above a certain value for y.

I cannot figure out how to access the vertices array inside the Face3.

I tried each of these separately to see if I could get the y value, but it always says cannot read property of undefined.

```
var face1 = new THREE.Face3(b, a, c );
            console.log(face1.a[1]);
            console.log(face1.a.y);
            console.log(face1[0].y)
```

The answer below works for the console.log, but I can't seem to change the vertex color once I have identified the ones that I want.

```
var faces = geometry.faces;
var vertices = geometry.vertices;
    for ( var i = 0; i < faces.length; i ++ ) {
            var face = faces[ i ];
            var vertexA = vertices[ face.a ];
            var vertexB = vertices[ face.b ];
            var vertexC = vertices[ face.c ];
            if (vertexA.y > 3.1 ){
                vertexA.color = colorPink;
                console.log(vertexA);
            } else if (vertexB.y > 3.1){
                vertexB.color = colorPink;
            } else if (vertexC.y > 3.1){
                vertexC.color = colorPink;
            }}
```

I don't get any console errors, but the vertex color is not changing. I don't want to change the entire face color, just the vertex that matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The properties `a`,`b` and `c` of `THREE.Face3` are indices. You can access the vertex values in this way:

```
var faces = geometry.faces;
var vertices = geometry.vertices;

for ( var i = 0; i < faces.length; i ++ ) {

    var face = faces[ i ];

    var vertex = vertices[ face.a ];

    console.log( vertex.y );

}
```

**Demo**: https://jsfiddle.net/f2Lommf5/6276/